# retrieve and set cookies

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

I'm trying to connect to a website that uses cookies. My login is as follows:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseurl);

            req.Referer = referer;
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            req.KeepAlive = true; 
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] postbuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(login);
            req.ContentLength = postbuf.Length;
            Stream rs = req.GetRequestStream();
            rs.Write(postbuf, 0, postbuf.Length);
            rs.Close();

            cookie = req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

            string s = "";
            foreach (Cookie c in cookie.GetCookies(req.RequestUri))
            {
                s += ("Cookie['" + c.Name + "']: " + c.Value);
            }
            textBox1.Text = s;

            resp.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

The cookie has 2 keys with values. Then I try to send a post request to the website as follows:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(search);

            req.Referer = referer;
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            req.KeepAlive = true;
            req.CookieContainer = cookie;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

            if (reader != null)
            {
                string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();

                textBox1.Text = data;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

But I get an error that it cannot authenticate. When I login using firefox, I see that the cookie contains much more entries.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Does the first response contain the .ASPXAUTH cookie?

Comment: Please don't put "C#" in the title.  That is what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your mistake is in the following line:

```
cookie = req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

you are instantiating a new cookie container every time after you write the request stream.

Since `cookie` is a global variable initialize it only once say for example where it's declared and set it before you write the stream:

```
req.CookieContainer = cookie;
rs.Write(postbuf, 0, postbuf.Length);
```

Comment: I changed the code and I can confirm that the login is being successful. But subsequent calls to the website still return "couldnt authenticate" even though I'm setting the cookie.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono - Are you setting the CookieContainer as new CookieContainer() on some other place in your code in those subsequent calls? The thing about CookieContainer is that you have to keep track of the old cookie container once you log in because it contains the login cookies. Once you set it to new you loose all the previous ones.